# What brass instrument is this?

Tags: sound-design, instruments

I would like to use an instrument on my song but I don't know what it is, for my it sounds like a trumpet or a trombone, somehow modified. Can anyone tell me precisely what instrument is this brass instrument playing on 2:08 of [Noel Gallagher’s High Flying Birds - The Death Of You And Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFx_IniNjfE)
? And also if it's modified some way?

And sorry if this is not the place to ask this kind of question, if it's not just tell me where to ask please.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a sax.

At 2:06 you distinctly hear a trombone slide being utilised, however, what's played after this - at 2:08 - is played in a register that is too high to be trombone. I'm positive it's trumpet. However - and very curiously - the trumpet player in this track is deliberately mimicking a technique that trumpet players have been practicing for decades - using a 'Harmon Mute' to alternately cover and uncover the trumpet bell, offering a 'wah-wah' effect. When I say 'mimicking', I mean that the trumpet player is not using a Harmon mute but using an electronic device to get the effect. 
I'm positive it's in fact a trumpet that's been filtered through either a 'wah-wah' device or an Envelope filter. An Envelope filter will give a wah-wah effect, varied depending on how forcibly the note is played.

Wah-wah is most common on stringed instruments, predominantly on guitar. Listen to the opening riff of Jimi Hendrix 'Voodoo Chile' - this is classic guitar/wah-wah.
Typically in music, there are no 'rules' laid-out that say wah-wah must be used exclusively for stringed instruments, in fact, I have an acquaintance who discretely routed a microphone through a wah-wah pedal just prior to Bingo being called. Interesting... Also, listen to the Steely Dan version of Duke Ellington's 'East St Louis Toodle-oo'. The guitar player uses a wah-wah pedal to mimic a trumpet player's Harmon mute technique.

Rodrigo, it's trumpet, but not as we know it...

Nice track, reminds me of 'Being For The Benefit Of Mr Kite' by The Beatles.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [saxophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxophone) (as seen in the video at 2:12).

You might be interested in using [DSK Saxophones](http://www.dskmusic.com/dsk-saxophones/), a free VST for Windows and OS X (both 32/64 bit).

Open source [ZynAddSubFX](http://zynaddsubfx.sourceforge.net/) has an ok-sounding synthesized [Saxophone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCQuVkDHsGU).

Perhaps it's an [Alto saxophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alto_saxophone), which you can find some free (attribution required) samples in [Alto Sax Extended Effects pack by YvesIV](http://freesound.org/people/YvesIV/packs/12234/)

Answer (score 0):

That's a trumpet for sure. It does seem to have some sort of muter or effect to mimic a muter, but the instrument under there? Definitely trumpet.